# Enabling "Use keyboard navigation" messes with NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I have an `NSTableView` where I use the

```
tableView(tableView:shouldTypeSelectFor:withCurrentSearch:) -> Bool
```

delegate method to select certain lines with the `SPACE` key like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,
               shouldTypeSelectFor event: NSEvent,
               withCurrentSearch searchString: String?) -> Bool {
    if event.charactersIgnoringModifiers == " " {
        // Perform action on currently selected row(s)
    }
    return false
}
```

That works fine, but when the setting in

```
Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls"
```

Is turned on, the table view loses focus entirely after hitting the `SPACE` key.
If I check my responder chain afterwards, I can se that the focus moved back to the window.

Another sideeffect of turning this setting on is that if I have a check box (`NSButton`) in the selected table view cell, its action will be automatically called when hitting `SPACE`.

The setting explicitly states it only moves focus on `TAB` and `SHIFT+TAB`, not change how controls work.

Why does this happen?
Can I disable this behavior at least partially for the table view of the app?

Comment: The space bar was used to select an item see [Use your keyboard like a mouse with Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-your-keyboard-like-a-mouse-mchlp1399/10.14/mac/10.14). How do you select a cell? Is the row selected or is the control in the cell focused?

Answer (score 2):

After almost losing my last hair here is what resolves it

- Make sure all your cell subviews have `refusesFirstResponder` set to `false`

Now the table views first responder status is not lost.